# Date and Time library that will support IE and Mozilla

Tags: angular

I have an angular7 application where i need to put date and time.so could you please suggest me library that will support all the browser. i search so many but not a single library that work with IE11

Answer (score 2):

Use **moment.js** : It is supported in all browsers.

```
  npm install moment --save   # npm
```

eg:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // March 4th 2019, 5:01:34 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Monday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Mar 4th 19
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2019 escaped 2019
```